# consulta multiple sql

Tags: sql

Tengo dos tablas una llamada obra con una pk llamada ID_PARAMETRI con datos como nombre_o , direccion , valor ect  y tengo otra llamada tabla llamada PARAMETRI la cual tiene un primarykey ID_PARAMETRI y datos como valor_multa ,multa_desface y dias_desface
 mi pregunta es como puedo hacer una consulta sql que me busque por el nombre de la obra y me traiga los datos de PARAMETRI segun el id, pero especifiacado los dato que quiero ejemplo 
de la tabla obra quiero ver el nombre y el valor y de la table PARARAMETRI quiero ver solo valor_multa y multa_desface

```
SELECT * FROM OBRA, PARAMETRI;
```

esta era la sentencia que tenia pero me trae todos los datos de ambas tablas

Comment: te sugiero ver primero un manual de SQL, sugerencia https://www.w3schools.com/sql/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Me parece extraño que en tus dos entidades, tengas la misma llave primaria ID_PARAMETRI, en algún lado debería de ser una FK o PK según la necesidad que se tenga.

Te comiendo ver teoría de conjuntos aplicada a base de datos te dejo un [link](https://webartesanal.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/08/Teoria-de-conjuntos-en-MySQL-con-select-join.jpg)

```
SELECT
    O.NOMBRE,
    O.VALOR,
    P.VALOR_MULTA,
    P.MULTA_DESFASE
FROM OBRA O 
 -- El inner join es la que te hace la intersección por medio de las llaves PK, FK
 INNER JOIN PARAMETRI P 
 ON O.ID_PARAMETRI = P.ID_PARAMETRI
 -- cuando son consultas más complejas podrías hacer el filtro en el on por ejemplo, y así evitar el where, en consultas más complejas es más rápido (según mi experiencia)
 -- AND O.NOMBRE = 'MIOBRA'
```

WHERE O.NOMBRE = 'MIOBRA'

otra forma según vi tu pregunta es que lo podés realizar así:

```
SELECT
    O.NOMBRE,
    O.VALOR,
    P.VALOR_MULTA,
    P.MULTA_DESFASE
FROM OBRA O, PARAMETRI P
WHERE O.ID_PARAMETRI = P.ID_PARAMETRI
AND O.NOMBRE = 'MIOBRA'
```

PS: Consejo no te creas eso de llaves compuestas, ya que al momento de utilizar un ORM por ejemplo, se trabajo una sola llave primaria para cada entidad y sus respectivas llaves foráneas.

Saludos,

Comment: las llaves compuestas claro que son usadas y las debe tener en cuenta, el hecho de que existan los ORM no implica que siempre se usan ni que por su existencia lo primero se debe olvidar

Answer (score 4):

La sentencia sería con un `JOIN` que une las dos tablas por su llave primaria / foránea.

Aquí uso dos alias cortos para cada tabla, `o` y `p`.

En la lista de columnas pones ese alias y el nombre de columna que necesitas.

Si quieres más filtros los puedes agregar con un `WHERE`.

```
SELECT
    o.nombre,
    o.valor,
    p.valor_multa,
    p.multa_desfase
FROM obra o
    INNER JOIN parametri p ON o.id_parametri = p.id_paramteri;
```